# Trying to learn rspec and TDD

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm having troubles with syntax error but I don't get why. I'm doing the example of 'The Rspec book' and I've got to some point where I can't go ahead. When I write in console rspec spec/codebreaker/game_spec.rb --format doc all I get is this message: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError) I've fixed this error thousands of time, but no matter what I do now I can't figure it out whats going on.

This is the code of spec/codebreaker/game_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

  module Codebreaker
   describe Game do
     describe "#start" do
       it "sends a welcome message"
         output = double('output')
         game = Game.new(output)
         output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to Codebreaker!')
         game.start
       end
       it "prompts for the first guess"
     end
   end
 end
```

I've added another 'end' and I've removed it as well but it doesn't work any way. May be I'm missing somethig about deprecated syntax or something. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a do after the it:
`it "sends a welcome message" do`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `end` for your second `it`:

```
it "prompts for the first guess"
end
```

You also must start your blocks with a `do`.

```
it "prompts for the first guess" do
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see it at all. Sorry for the dum question.